# collection not loading in pdf file in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have to export data in pdf of orders in *Magento*

But i got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection::getSelect() in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php on line 1683

my code for getpdf action

```
public function getPdfFile(){

    $this->_isExport = true;
    $this->_prepareGrid();

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit();
    $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(0);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    $this->_afterLoadCollection();

    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
    $page->setFont($font, 12);
    $width = $page->getWidth();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
    if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
        $i+=10;
        $header = $column->getExportHeader();                
        $page->drawText($header, $i, $page->getHeight()-20);                
        $width = $font->widthForGlyph($font->glyphNumberForCharacter($header));
        $i+=($width/$font->getUnitsPerEm()*12)*strlen($header)+10;
     }
    }
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

and my controller action code is

```
public function exportPdfAction(){

$fileName = 'daily_orders.pdf';        

$content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reportneworders/adminhtml_reportneworders_grid')->getPdfFile();

$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```

}

*grid is working proper in admin.*

csv and excel data export sucessfully but pdf cannot. any one please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach ($this->_columns as $column)` statement which you have only prints the headers of the grid.
You have to iterate through the collection of items as well. Before the `$pdf->pages[] = $page;` line, add something like this:

```php
$j = 40;
foreach ($collection as $item) {
  //  add code here, which is printing $item information
  //  Example:
  $y = $page->getHeight()-$j;
  $page->drawText($item->getincrement_id(), 20, $y);
  $page->drawText($item->getcreated_at(), 50, $y);
  // etc.
  $j += 20;
}
```

Also, in my own code, in order the PDF export to respond to the **grid filters**, I had to change the `function exportPdfAction()` code to the following (otherwise filters were ignored):

```
public function exportPdfAction(){
   $fileName = 'daily_orders.pdf';        
   $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reportneworders/adminhtml_reportneworders_grid');
   $this->_initReportAction($grid);
   $content = $grid->getPdfFile();
   $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
}
```

As you see, I have added the `$this->_initReportAction($grid);`